# PHP Foreach Column Data Wise

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I want to make for-each loop where div will echo `qty` as the diagram below -
for example, the div will echo `2` times for `product1` and the same for `product2` `6` times.

I know the for-each function in PHP but don't know how to echo some columns data-wise. I have also seen some threads on StackOverflow but it was not understood by me.

Please help me -

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM product_name");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach ($result as $data => $logs) {
  if (!empty($logs)) { ?>
    <div class="myClass" id="count1"><?= $logs['name'] ?></div>
<?php } } ?>

table : product_name

|---------------------------------------|
| ID   |  name      |  qty              |
-----------------------------------------
| 1    | product1   |   2               |
-----------------------------------------
| 2    | product2   |   6               |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: It will be good if you update `$result` array so some one can use that array and provide you answer accordingly

Comment: Please help.. I could not understand your answer... I undated the question

Comment: Update your question with the more specific data. What is the values of `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();` `print_r($result)` and put in your question

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you need to use one another loop for print repeated row as per your qty field.

```
For(var i=1;i<=qty;i++){
<div class="myClass" id="count1"><?= $logs['name'] ?></div>
}
```

I am not php developer so you need to correct the syntax but i tried to help using logically.